# How to correct symbol lookup error in MongoDb C client

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

When I run the [hello_mongoc](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/tutorial.html#making-a-connection) test app (renamed to mongotest), the output looks like this:

```
{ "ok" : 1 }
./mongotest: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: bson_validate_with_error
```

The app is build with:

```
cc -o mongotest mongotest.o -lmongoc-1.0 -lbson-1.0
```

and gives no compilation warnings/errors.

This is in /usr/local/lib:

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff      16 Oct  5 11:38 libbson-1.0.so -> libbson-1.0.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff      20 Oct  5 11:38 libbson-1.0.so.0 -> libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  549180 Oct  5 11:29 libbson-1.0.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff  744738 Oct  5 11:30 libbson-static-1.0.a
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff      18 Oct  5 11:38 libmongoc-1.0.so -> libmongoc-1.0.so.0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root staff      22 Oct  5 11:38 libmongoc-1.0.so.0 -> libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff 2162580 Oct  5 11:31 libmongoc-1.0.so.0.0.0
-rw-r--r--  1 root staff 3553982 Oct  5 11:33 libmongoc-static-1.0.a
```

I am running on a raspberry pi 3B+

Answer (score 0):

According to [`libbson` source](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson), [`bson_validate_with_error` was added in `1.7.0`](https://github.com/mongodb/libbson/commit/a60043f71f91e7578887ffad451d18c8b7d04599), while you have `1.0`.

EDIT 1:

This seems to be a linker issue. More info in comments below.

EDIT 2:

One way of solving this is to use static linking:

```
gcc -o mongotest mongotest.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-static-1.0)
```

Comment: As far as I can tell I am using the most recent version (1.13) of mongo-c-driver: http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/installing.html , or do you know of a more recent one?

Comment: I checked, and `validate_with_error` does exist in the bson lib that I am using. So there must be something wrong with the linking process?

Comment: I believe the documentation might be out of date, and hence you're installing quite old version. What I can suggest - build and install library by yourself. Check out the sources, then run: `autoconf`, `/.configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`.

Comment: This is exactly what I did. Therefore I can see in the source (`bson.c`) that the function `validate_with_error` does exist in the lib that I build.

Comment: Could you provide output of following: `readelf -Ws /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0`

Comment: `readelf -Ws /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0 | grep validate_with_error
   269: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bson_validate_with_error

  4021: 00000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND bson_validate_with_error`

Comment: and the same for libbson:
`readelf -Ws /usr/local/lib/libbson-1.0.so.0 | grep validate_with_error
   239: 0000f51c    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 bson_validate_with_error
  1298: 0000f51c    72 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   11 bson_validate_with_error`

Comment: Ok, this might sound strange to you, but please try to reorder libraries in a command line that links your binary: `cc -o mongotest mongotest.o -lbson-1.0 -lmongoc-1.0`, and report your observations.

Comment: same result:
`{ "ok" : 1 }
./mongotest: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libmongoc-1.0.so.0: undefined symbol: bson_validate_with_error`

Comment: It's clear that it has something to do with the linker. Is there any particular reason why you are not using `pkg-config`? Like: `gcc -o mongotest mongotest.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-1.0)`

Comment: This is my first C-project again since 20 years so I don't know `pkg-config` ;) But I will do some research now... Thanks for your tips!

Comment: `pkg-config` adds all the dependencies for you, so you don't have to mess around with flags or libraries. I'm pretty sure you will get past this problem by using the command I provided (which, by the way, is used MongoDB C Driver tutorial).

Comment: finally got it working with: `gcc -o mongotest mongotest.c $(pkg-config --libs --cflags libmongoc-static-1.0)`

Comment: Glad to hear! I've updated my answer, so others could potentially save some time.